# Online Payment with Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, payment

I am working with Rails 3.0.3. I am new to it. In my project, I need to provide online payments. Can anyone help with proper procedure for it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at active merchant. This should fit almost all of your needs about online payment integration.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/144-active-merchant-basics
http://railscasts.com/episodes/145-integrating-active-merchant
http://railscasts.com/episodes/146-paypal-express-checkout